# Will tail search in new folders created after tail stream started?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have this command for the windows cmd window:

```
tail -f *.log
```

I do the following:

1. Have a folder with a number of .log files.
2. Call the command: tail -f *.log
3. Create a new .log file

My question is now if the command will start streaming from the new file as well? Or if it requires a restart of the command?

Thanks

Comment: `tail` is not a command supplied with Microsoft Windows. The `tail` from Cygwin will follow multiple files, but it will not recognize files created after `tail -f` starts. A lot of this depends on where you got your `tail` from.

Comment: @Liturgist How do I check where I have got it from. As it is on my work computer, I don't know. It just is there.

Comment: This is easy enough to test yourself. Create two files and start the `tail -f` command. In another shell cmd window, create a third file that matches the pattern that tail is following. To know from whence your `tail` comes, use `tail --version` or `tail -v` or `tail -h`.